# override list view for custom object with lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view

I have a custom object that I need to override the list view functionality with an LWC instead of the OOTB list view. It looks like I can only do that with a VF page (no LWC option).
[image]
Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, when you scroll down on the Tabs page in setup, there is a handy section called **Lightning Component Tabs**. There you can create a tab and select the LWC you want to use with it. Remember to associate the tab with the app you're want to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method that is a standard override.

There is a (much) more complex route that is likely a lot of development for the benefit that you need.  That is to create a page in the lightning app builder and then create your own lwc component that repeats the custom view - perhaps using a datatable type approach.

You could consider an aura component (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView).

I think my general advice would not to go down this development route though.

Comment: Thanks @andy-nix - so I've already created a page with lightning app builder and built out the list view with LWC. I'm trying to understand how to use that view instead of the OOTB list view when clicking on the custom object tab.  The only way I've found to do it would be to create a vf page to house the LWC. Looked unnecessarily complex. I was hoping there was an easier way.